# Chromium replace newtab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I would like to replace newtab in chromium with my own tab. As I understand I could make an extension for this purpose. 
Is there a way to make my extension always enabled and to make a user forbidden to uninstall it? I want to make it preinstalled as a native part of my own browser.

The main idea to replace newtab in chromium to my own tab permanently. I found a solution in extensions. Is there a way to do it not by creating extension but by changing source code of chromium?

Thanks

Comment: You can definitely do it by changing the source code, no doubt. A simpler method is setting a [NewTabPageLocation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=NewTabPageLocation) policy.

Comment: To do all of that, you will have to modify the Chromium source code. This is a very broad topic